# Organise data by likelihood and create new columns with the newly organised values in Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, split, series

I am totally new to Python so I would appreciate your patience if my question is not totally clear or if it is too obvious.

I need to organise the data using a condition and then create new columns with the newly organised data. I've created a short example to illustrate my point. Let's say S is my data to be organised and split.

Here is what I need to do :

1. Find the likelihood of adjacent elements by calculating their ratio. For example, if `1.3 > S[i]/S[i+1] > 0.80`, the values should stored in a series, let's say, `a`.
2. If the condition is not satisfied, create a new series `b` to be filled up with the next `S[i+1]` until the condition is respected.
3. Else, create a new series `c`... and start all over again.

**Example**

```
S=pd.Series([9,9,10,11,12,10,22,23,21,20,21,33,35,37,34,50,51,56,48,51])

a =[]
b = []
c = []
d = []

i=0
j = 1
k=1
m=1


for i in range(0,19,1):
    if 1.3 > S[i]/S[i+1] > 0.80: 
        a.append(S[i])
        j +=1
    else:
      break

for i in range(j,19,1):
      if 1.3 > S[i]/S[i+1] > 0.80: 
          b.append(S[i])
          k +=1
      else:
          break

for i in range(j+k,19,1):
    if 1.3 > S[i]/S[i+1] > 0.80: 
        c.append(S[i])
        m +=1
    else:
        break


for i in range(j+k+m,19,1):
    if 1.3 > S[i]/S[i+1] > 0.80:
        d.append(S[i])
    else:
        break


print('a=',a,'b=',b,'c=',c,'d=',d)

a= [9, 9, 10, 11, 12] 
b= [22, 23, 21, 20] 
c= [33, 35, 37] 
d= [50, 51, 56, 48]
```

There are two main issues about this code :

First, there is a problem. The last number of each generated series is missing. For example, in series `b`, the term `21` is missing.

And second, is it possible to use loops to generate the series as needed ? The real data has 10000+ rows and hundreds of different series may be needed.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You are using global variables inside loops so they don't have a definition inside. One thing you could do is use `global`  keyword like `global variable_name` inside loop that uses it.

Comment: @0decimal0 Thanks for your promptness. I didn't know about global. Will check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you are asking, but not 100% sure.  Assuming I've interpreted the question correctly, here is what I think you are looking for.

```
def bucket_nums(numbers):
    groups = collections.defaultdict(list)
    i = 0
    while i < len(numbers) - 1:
        j = i
        #bug here: num[i+1] gets incremented before the bounds test
        while 1.3 > numbers[i]/numbers[i+1] > 0.8 and i < len(numbers)- 2: #also should be -1, not -2 (this is why it skipped the last one)
            groups['group{}'.format(j)].append(numbers[i])
            i += 1
        groups['group{}'.format(j)].append(numbers[i])
        i += 1
    return groups
```

**EDIT:**

You are correct, the code had a bug.  I was testing the index bounds after potentially incrementing past the list length, and then incorrectly compensated for it by decreasing the index check to `< [i+2]`.  Below is the fixed code.  Leaving the unfixed version to publicly shame myself for being lazy and trying to crank out an answer too fast for them points.

```
def bucket_nums(numbers):
    groups = collections.defaultdict(list)
    i = 0
    while i < len(numbers):
        j = i
        while i < len(nums) - 1:
            if  1.3 > numbers[i] / numbers[i+1] > 0.8:  
                groups['group{}'.format(j)].append(numbers[i])
                i += 1
            else:
                break
        groups['group{}'.format(j)].append(numbers[i])
        i += 1
    return groups
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your post. As I'm learning it will take me a moment to understand it and to apply it to my data.I will write you back when I test it.

Comment: Did I do that ? I dont see your answer anymore. Don't know what happened. I was writting you a message and your answer disappeared.
Please excuse me if I did that and if there a way to see your answer again ?

Comment: @The_rookie if this solves your problem, and I believe it should, please undo the downvote and accept the answer :)  If you need help understanding it, I can try to explain further. In short, it replicates your process without the manual repeating of each for loop.

Comment: I have tested it and it does the job. Thanks a lot. There is only one little detail, the last number does not appear. In my example, that means that 51 is missing.
And I just can't manage to undo the downvote @solaxun. I have tried and read some posts and it seems you have to a special right to downvote. I'm a bit confused here.

Comment: Don't sweat the downvote.  Especially since I gave you the wrong answer.  I probably deserve it! :)

Comment: @Solax Thanks again!  I'm a real beginner and Im combining my work with learning python so sometimes I have no time to check this post.
And I'm still curious about this downvote thing. I haven't done it, at least on purpuse. Not even sure how you do it...